# ¿Cómo listar las aplicaciones instaladas con adb?

Tags: android, adb

He probado lo siguiente:

```
adb shell
cd system/app
ls
```

Pero lo anterior sólo me lista las aplicaciones que están instaladas por defecto en el sistema, hay alguna forma de listar todas las aplicaciones instaladas en el teléfono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mostrar todos los paquetes que identifican a una aplicación y estan instalados en el dispositivo mediante `Android Debug Bridge`, puedes realizarlo con la secuencia:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages
```

Para mostrar los paquetes de las aplicaciones de sistema:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -s
```

Si deseas ver los apk instalados así como su ruta a los mismos:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con este comando dentro del shell
`pm list packages -f`

Answer (score 0):

Añado a lo que dijo Jorgesys lo siguiente que puede ser de utilidad:

Para mostrar los paquetes filtrándolos por su nombre, dev o palabra clave:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages | grep nombre
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages | grep google
```

En caso de ya haber entrado a adb shell, los comandos son los mismos pero quitando *adb shell*

Para desinstalar apps (incluso de sistema) sin root:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall -k –-user 0 nombreDePaquete
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall -k –-user 0 com.google.android.youtube
```

Prestar atención al doble guión antes de "user".